# Distance between compact set and closed set in metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

The accepted answer in

[If $C \subset U$ is compact, $U$ open with compact closure in a metric space $M$, then there exist open $V$ st $C \subset V \subset \bar V \subset U$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310094/if-c-subset-u-is-compact-u-open-with-compact-closure-in-a-metric-space-m?rq=1)

states

> Since $C$ is compact and $\partial U$ is closed, $d(C,\partial U)=d(x,y)$ for some $x\in C,\ y\in\partial U$. And since $C\subset U$ with $U$ open, we have
>   $$d_0=d(C,\partial U)=d(x,y)>0$$

But is this true for the infinite-dimensional case as well? For example (there are many related questions in the finite-dimensional setting) in the proof

[$X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Define $d(K, F) = \inf\{ d(x,y), x \in K, y \in F\}$, show that $d(a,b) = d(K,F)$ for some $a$, $b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87710/x-y-subset-mathbbrn-define-dk-f-inf-dx-y-x-in-k-y-in-f?noredirect=1&lq=1)

closed and bounded sets being compact is crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say $d(C,\partial U)>0$, I have realized one can use this:
[A and B disjoint, A compact, and B closed implies there is positive distance between both sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/a-and-b-disjoint-a-compact-and-b-closed-implies-there-is-positive-distance-bet)

Indeed, since $U$ is open, $U\cap \partial U=\emptyset$. But $C\subset U$ implies $C\cap \partial U=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. In this case we can only find $x\in C$ for any $y\in\partial U$ such that $d(x,y)=d(C,y)$. For example, if we consider the space $\ell^2 (\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} )$ with $C=\{e_1 =(1,0,0,\dotsb )\} $ and $U=\{(x_1 ,x_2 ,\dotsb ,x_n ,\dotsb )\vert x_1 >0\} $, then $\partial U=\{(0,x_2 ,x_3 ,\dotsb )\} $ and let $e_i =(0,0,\dotsb ,0,1,0,\dotsb )$, we have $d(e_1 ,e_i )=\Vert e_i -e_1 \Vert\equiv\sqrt{2} $.